# Javascript then() chaining - which Deferred does the second then() correspond to?

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

1) I have a chain of jquery then(), like this:

```
someAjax().then(function(val) { console.log("done 1: " + val); return val + 1; },
                function(val) { console.log("fail 1: " + val); return val + 2; },
                function(val) { console.log("prog 1: " + val); return val + 3; }

         ).then(function(val) { console.log("done 2: " + val) },
                function(val) { console.log("fail 2: " + val) },
                function(val) { console.log("prog 2: " + val) }
         )
```

I understand that the three functions (three args) of the **first** then() correspond to the states of the Deferred object from someAjax().

However, I don't understand, what Deferred object do the three functions (args) of the **second** then correspond to? For example, what if (or is it possible that) each of the three function of the **first** then() may return its own Deferred object?

I feel like I may misunderstand something in here. Appreciate any clarification.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

2) I have another chaining like this:

```
$.getJSON(url).then(
                doneFunction1,
                errorFunction1
            ).then(
                doneFunction2
            });
```

The doneFunction1 looks like this:

```
function doneFunction1(val){
   if(val > 1)
      return $.ajax(url2);
}
```

So this does not always returns a promise, as you see, depending on `val`.
In case it does not return a Promise (say val < 1), how does the second then proceed? Would that cause an error? Because as I understand, there is no Promise to call then() on. My guess is that it may just call the then() of the first Promise of `$.getJSON` but I may be wrong.

Basically, I am trying NOT to have the second `then()` at all when `val < 1'. Is it possible?

Comment: it refers to whatever you return from the first .then promise

Comment: `.then` generally only takes two functions, the first one is called when the promise resolves, the second when it's rejected ?

Comment: Noting that you're using jQuery, and not proper A+ promises, would be rather important here !

Comment: @adeneo: some Promise implementations have progress reporting built-in, like the famous Q lib by Kris Kowal

Comment: @TamasHegedus - And jQuery, but native promises do not, the native `.then` method only accepts two callbacks, which is why I asked, before the OP edited the question and it was clear that jQuery was being used.

Comment: You should ask a single question per post only. Please [edit] out the second one, and ask it separately (or just [search for a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[promise]+break+chain))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return a Deferred that is either resolved or rejected

```
function doneFunction1(val){
    if(val > 1) {
        return $.ajax(url2);
    } else {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        return def.reject(); // or def.resolve('something'); to hit the success handler
    }
}

$.getJSON(url).then(
    doneFunction1,
    errorFunction1
).then(
    doneFunction2,
    errorFunction2 // only needed if you want to catch the error
});
```